# Offline Wiki in eclipse that deals with links

Tags: gratis, offline, wiki, eclipse

I need an offline wiki that runs inside eclipse. Must be open source / free / any no-cost option.

Mylyn [WikiText](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Mylyn/WikiText) would be perfect if [textile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Textile_%28markup_language%29) could deal with internal links (like all other wikis), but despite it's called "wiki", actually it seems just a markup language that simplifies HTML a little bit, allowing links to external sites, but not linking easily from one page to another.

By offline I mean: no server involved. I just want something integrated in eclipse.

Why not HTML? Because it cannot render links automatically. If I wanted just a markup language, Mylyn WikiText would fit better than HTML.

For example, in most wikis, if I write **ThisCamelCaseWord**, the wiki renderer automatically creates a link to the page of **ThisCamelCaseWord**. Mylyn WikiText, instead, does not support such a feature (because textile does not).

Answer (score 2):

You could try **[Eclipse Markdown Editor Plugin](https://github.com/winterstein/Eclipse-Markdown-Editor-Plugin)**, which is freely available at Github. Syntax isn't CamelCase, but – as the name suggests – [Markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown), a fairly wide-spread and easy to learn markup languag--e; in fact the same thing we use here at SE, or what Github itself is using. Even its plain-text (what you write) is fairly easy to read, and many other places/projects can handle it – which IMHO makes it a first-choice in development. This editor of course features a preview:

[image: Eclipse Markdown Editor Plugin]
<sup>*Eclipse Markdown Editor Plugin* (source: [Github](https://github.com/winterstein/Eclipse-Markdown-Editor-Plugin); click image for larger variant)</sup>

See also:

- [Eclipse Markdown Plugin - How to open Markdown HTML Preview when double clicking a .md file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19010407/2533433) (SO)
- [Markdown Text Editor 1.2.0](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/markdown-text-editor) (the very same one at the Eclipse market place)
- [What Markdown Editor is Best to Use?](http://br0sk.blogspot.com/2012/01/what-markdown-editor-is-best-to-use.html) (recommends the very same thing for Eclipse)

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is **[TiddlyWiki](http://tiddlywiki.com/)**. It's not an Eclipse plugin, but it works offline and doesn't need a server. It uses Javascript to do all it needs, and saves the end result to a file on your computer. Changing the wiki can only be done locally, reading the end result can be local or on a webserver.

TiddlyWiki is basically a onepage wiki. All data is stored in one file or one page with foldable items. This can be limiting for larger wikis. It can link to other wiki's, and it should be possible to link to other TiddlyWikis on the same filesystem I guess - I haven't tried this.